# Expecting dict; got: shell:Error

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am getting the below error

```
ERROR: expecting dict; got: shell:"ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt" register:the_file
```

1. I want to check the folder is exist.
2. if exist I need to specify some path /mule/acc
3. if the path does not exist need to point /mule/bcc

The following is ansible playbook

```
---
# get name of the .txt file
- stat: path=/mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1
  register:the_file  
  when: the_file.stat.exists == True
- shell:"ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register:the_file  
- debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"
- set_fact: app_folder="{{ the_file.stdout | replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"
- debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"
- debug: msg="{{ the_file.stdout }}"
# delete the .txt file
- name: Delete the anchor.txt file
  file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent
# wait until the app folder disappears
- name: Wait for the folder to disappear
  wait_for: path="{{ app_folder }}" state=absent
# copy the zip file
- name: Copy the zip file
  copy: src="../p" dest="/c"
```

Comment: on which task you are getting this error? can you paste the complete playbook and it's execution

Comment: Need to check /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1 path.if not i need to look in to different path.The above script is working fine for single path.I have to copy the file into 2 differt host with same file name but with different path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have the YAML right, but there is one YAML error in your file and that is on the line:

```
register:the_file
```

because the line preceding it starts the first element of the toplevel sequence as a mapping through defining a key-value pair based on the colon ('`:`') followed by space, and that cannot be followed by a scalar (or a sequence). *If that file was your input, you would have gotten a syntax error by the YAML parser* with part of the message looking like:

```
      register:the_file
      ^
could not find expected ':'
```

This:

```
- shell:"ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register:the_file
```

is perfectly fine YAML. It defines the second element of the top-level sequence to be a scalar string:

```
shell:"ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt" register:the_file
```

(you can break scalar strings over multiple lines in YAML).

Now ansible doesn't like that and expects that element, and probably all top-level sequence elements, to be mappings. And for a mapping you need to have a key value pair, which is (like with `register:the_file`) separated/indicated by a colon-space pair of characters in YAML. So ansible (not YAML) probably wants:

```
shell: ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt
register: the_file
```

please note that the quotes around the scalar value `ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt` are unnecessary in YAML.

There might be other things ansible expects from the structure of the file, but I would start with the above change and see if ansible throws further errors on:

```
# get name of the .txt file
- stat: path=/mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1
  register: the_file
  when: the_file.stat.exists == True
- shell: ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt
  register: the_file
- debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"
- set_fact: app_folder="{{ the_file.stdout | replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"
- debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"
- debug: msg="{{ the_file.stdout }}"
# delete the .txt file
- name: Delete the anchor.txt file
  file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent
# wait until the app folder disappears
- name: Wait for the folder to disappear
  wait_for: path="{{ app_folder }}" state=absent
# copy the zip file
- name: Copy the zip file
  copy: src="../analytic-core-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn YAML syntax. After every colon you are required to add a whitespace. The message comes from the YAML parser, telling you it expected a dictionary:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

Instead it found no key-value-pair:

```
key1:value1
```

Specifically it complains about this line:

```
- shell:"ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
```

which should be

```
- shell: "ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
```

But you have the same issue in two more lines which look like:

```
register:the_file
```

and should be :

```
register: the_file
```

If in doubt an error comes from Ansible tasks or simply from a YAML parsing error, paste your YAML definition into any [online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---%0A%23%20get%20name%20of%20the%20.txt%20file%0A-%20stat%3A%20path%3D%2Fmule%2Fansiple%2Fmule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1%0A%20%20register%3Athe_file%20%20%0A%20%20when%3A%20the_file.stat.exists%20%3D%3D%20True%0A-%20shell%3A%22ls%20%2Fmule%2Fansiple%2Fmule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1%2F*.txt%22%0A%20%20register%3Athe_file%20%20%0A-%20debug%3A%20msg%3D%22%7B%7B%20the_file%20%7D%7D%22%0A-%20set_fact%3A%20app_folder%3D%22%7B%7B%20the_file.stdout%20%7C%20replace(%27-anchor.txt%27%2C%27%27)%20%7D%7D%22%0A-%20debug%3A%20msg%3D%22%7B%7B%20app_folder%20%7D%7D%22%0A-%20debug%3A%20msg%3D%22%7B%7B%20the_file.stdout%20%7D%7D%22%0A%23%20delete%20the%20.txt%20file%0A-%20name%3A%20Delete%20the%20anchor.txt%20file%0A%20%20file%3A%20path%3D%22%7B%7B%20the_file.stdout%20%7D%7D%22%20state%3Dabsent%0A%23%20wait%20until%20the%20app%20folder%20disappears%0A-%20name%3A%20Wait%20for%20the%20folder%20to%20disappear%0A%20%20wait_for%3A%20path%3D%22%7B%7B%20app_folder%20%7D%7D%22%20state%3Dabsent%0A%23%20copy%20the%20zip%20file%0A-%20name%3A%20Copy%20the%20zip%20file%0A%20%20copy%3A%20src%3D%22..%2Fanalytic-core-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip%22%20%20%20%20%20dest%3D%22%2Fmule%2Fansiple%2Fmule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1%22&type=json).

So much for the format. Now to logical problems:

```
- stat: path=/mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1
  register: the_file  
  when: the_file.stat.exists == True
```

Unless you have `the_file` already registered from a previous task you didn't show, this can't work. `when` is the condition to decide if the task should be run. You can not execute a task depending on its outcome. It first has to run before the result is available. At the time the condition is evaluated `the_file` simply won't exist and this should result in an error, complaining that a *None* object does not have a key `stat` or something similar.

Then in the next task you again register the result with the same name.

```
- shell: "ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register: the_file
```

This simply will override the previous registered result. Maybe you meant to have the condition from the first task on the second. But even that would not work. A result still will be registered from skipped tasks, simply stating the task was skipped. You either need to store the results in unique vars or check all possible file locations in a single task.

Cleaned up your playbook would look like this:

```
---
# get name of the .txt file
- stat:
    path: /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1
  register: the_file
  when: the_file.stat.exists

- shell: ls /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt
  register: the_file

- debug:
    msg: "{{ the_file }}"

- set_fact:
    app_folder: "{{ the_file.stdout | replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ app_folder }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ the_file.stdout }}"

- name: Delete the anchor.txt file
  file:
    path: "{{ the_file.stdout }}"
    state: absent

- name: Wait for the folder to disappear
  wait_for:
    path: "{{ app_folder }}"
    state: absent

- name: Copy the zip file
  copy:
    src: ../analytic-core-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
    dest: /mule/ansiple/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1

...
```

Comment: It is not required to have a space after every colon in YAML (`abc:def` is a perfectly fine YAML file defining a 7 character scalar). The message the op gets doesn't come from the YAML parser. The online YAML parser you recommend cannot handle files following the YAML 1.2 specification (published in 2009), and cannot handle all YAML 1.1 (from 2005). It might be that is irrelevant for ansible, but it is confusing if you recommend such tools for learning YAML in 2016.

Comment: I admit I _assumed_ this is generally required in YAML, since both Ansible and the online parser require the space. Appears like both only support YAML 1.0 then.

Comment: Ansible uses [PyYAML](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/setup.py#L25) which is almost YAML 1.1. And it ansible that seems to insist on mapping as the top-level sequence items.